# Is there a Mac browser that is capable of printing a java app?

Tags: mac, browser, printing, java-applet

We use a third-party java applet to generate graphs. One of our customers reports that on her Mac, she can see the graphs in the browser, but she cannot print them: the rest of the page prints just fine, but there's a blank space where the graph should be. She has tried in both Safari and Firefox (latest versions of both, as far as we can ascertain).

Note that we've been using the app for many years now, and this printing issue periodically rears its head, then people give up and just switch to using Internet Explorer (which is the *only* browser that reliably prints the graphs). The difference in this case is that this customer does not have a Windows computer available to her, and she does not have the technical expertise to install and run Windows in a virtual machine. We, on the other hand, do not have a Mac available to us, which makes troubleshooting this... well, interesting.

Is there any way to convince a browser, any browser, on a Mac to print the contents of a java applet?

<sub>Note that it's **not** the applet itself that is trying (and failing) to print. The applet simply generates a pretty picture, and the browser is supposed to print out said pretty picture along with the rest of the page (text, graphics, whatnot). I mention this because trying to search the web about this issue is almost impossible, since most of the results go off about print methods and classes and other java jibberish.</sub>

Comment: Hello, please ask the client to give more information on Firefox. Open a new tab, type **about:support**, click "Copy all to clipboard" at page top. Paste to a pastebin (like http://www.dpaste.com) and edit your question to include the paste URL. Thank you.

Comment: @gry, just want to note that I haven't forgotten about this question or your request for more information, but everyone seems to be on vacation at this time of year. (I'm not sure I will be able to get the Firefox information from this client, but I will try as soon as she comes back from vacation.)